# Cannot open local .txt file to read in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm not an experienced programmer and I am solely trying to use it for some data analysis with NLTK. I'm following the online book, but the following code does not open to read the file.

```
#download nltk

import nltk
nltk.download()

#import everything from nltk
from nltk.book import *

import io
open('ALL FEMALES1.txt', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

The output:
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='ALL FEMALES1.txt' mode='r' encoding='ISO-8859-1'>

I've tried to use

```
f = open('ALL FEMALES1.txt')
>>> raw = f.read()
```

But this gives me the following error:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 18929: invalid continuation byte

Any advice? I'm using Jupyter Notebook if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Opening files can be nicely done with

```
with open('sample_file.txt', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    print(f.read())
```